# Can "the restaurant you told me was not good" used as noun?

Tags: meaning, sentence

The restaurant you told me was not good.

If there is a sentence like this, it most of the times means that "*the restaurant you told me about was not good.*"

So when can this sentence be used with the same meaning as "*the food I thought to be good*"? In other words, like a noun?

Comment: The restaurant you told me was not good is actually not too bad. 'The restaurant you told me was not good' is ungrammatical, though may occur in colloquial chat. As you say, 'The restaurant you told me about was not good' – or 'The restaurant you showed me was not good'.

Comment: Why is it ungrammatical? I thoguht that sentences like "the restaurant I thoght was good" is grammatical.

Comment: Unless you are using a report structure ('The restaurant, you told me, was not good' = 'You told me that the restaurant was not good') (which needs the commas), 'The restaurant you told me was not good' is not a complete statement. It is like 'The bill you promised you'd pay.' 'The man I saw.'

Comment: What if I use it with which like this: the restaurant which you told me was not good. Do I still need comma like this? The restaurant which, you told me, was not good. It seems to me that there is subtle difference between them.

Comment: It doesn't stand on its own. It's like saying 'the restaurant down the street'.

Comment: You could use it like this:  "I went to *the restaurant you told me was not good*, and I thought it was actually pretty nice."

Comment: @ I mean when used in a sentence, not when standing on its own like "not good man".

Comment: Apparently you need to be clearer about terminology. "The restaurant you told me was not good", as a sentence, is badly formed though, as Edwin said, would probably pass muster in casual conversation. As a noun phrase, used together with a verb and another noun (phrase) to make up a sentence, it is perfectly normal.

Comment: In "The restaurant you told me was not good turned out to be quite delightful", the "raw" subject is "restaurant" and "you told me was not good" is effectively an adjective on "restaurant" (though don't ask me for the formal term).

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to say it, but it's correct:

We ate at the restaurant you told me to avoid. (We did it anyway)

We ate at the restaurant you told me was bad. (It wasn't)

We ate at the restaurant you told me was not good. (It was)